# How to compare string value of databound textbox

Tags: c#

So I am trying to make a program that allows the user to select currently 1 of 3 colors, then click on a picture box to change its back color, then save the colors selected and be able to load those colors back to the picture boxes. How I started this project was by setting up a service database that saves and loads text box strings. 
This is what I used to create the color variable.

```
Color color = Color.White;
```

The picture below shows the layout of the form.
[image]

When the user clicks on the blue coloured picturebox this happens

```
private void pictureBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    color = Color.Blue;
}
```

Then when the user clicks on the blank picture box that he/she wants to change colour this happens.

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackColor = color;

    if (color == Color.Red)
    {
        grid1TextBox.Text = ("Red");
    }

    if (color == Color.Green)
    {
        grid1TextBox.Text = ("Green");
    }

    if (color == Color.Blue)
    {
        grid1TextBox.Text = ("Blue");
    }
}
```

After the user has selected a colour and changed a blank picturebox to whichever colour they chose, the grid1TextBox.Text gets updated with the new text, either Blue, Green or Red depending on the colour chosen. Then the user can type in a name for the creation in the creation title textbox and finally click save.

**So now for the problem**. Once the program saves that text box info all seems good but if the user clicks new for a blank set of picture boxes then tries loading the previous creation by typing in the creation title in the search box and clicking search an issue arises. After clicking search the program will display the text saved in those grid text boxes correctly but nothing else happens.

What is supposed to happen is

```
if (grid1TextBox.Text == "Red")
{
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    MessageBox.Show("worked");
}
```

But the pictureboxes remain blank. The code above is called after the values of the databound textboxes have been loaded.

Which should mean that the blank pictureboxes will change to the depicted colour of the textbox. But no. Nothing Works.

First time using stackoverflow not sure if this explaination of my problem is clear understood but hey I guess you guys will tell me.